# How to report a post to moderators?

Tags: support

I read (not all but) many questions about automatic bounty awarding. e.g.:
*[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)* and *[Automatic award of bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299807/automatic-award-of-bounty)*.

And in *[How to willingly not award a bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260141/how-to-willingly-not-award-a-bounty)* I found:

> ... after all. If you think the upvotes are fraudulent, you should
>   report the post to the mods. ...

But how?

Background:
I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554450/what-is-the-reason-that-rendering-same-haml-is-much-slower-when-ajax-than-loadi) about Ruby on Rails and Haml. After 'bountying' it, I got an answer that does not even fit to my question. So I voted it down, but for some reason it got the additional three votes to qualify for the automatic award system. And the answer would not be qualified for upvoting (it's confusing, and no explanation) even it would fit to my question.

And it's the copy of *[Ruby on Rails Ajax call runs controller code, returns success, but not rendering view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215547/rails-ajax-call-runs-controller-code-returns-success-but-not-rendering-view)*.

Comment: You can click flag > other and then explain what you have found and needs to be looked at, Be sure to be as complete as possible

Comment: I need better glasses, thanks

Comment: You are going to report the plagiarism and the upvotes, right? You won't get the bounty refunded so don't ask for that in your flag.

Comment: @rene: I don't ask for 'refund' - and it is not even 'plagiarism' it's just cut and past of *any* answer

Comment: Ok, good. Well, using the word plagiarism does normally help to trigger Brad Larson, the mod who handles those cases often.

Comment: you did flag for a moderator, right? or did you also flag for very low quality?

Comment: FYI the answer was in [LQP queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17125112) however at the time of reviewing I had no information that it was plagiarized from another answer, hence it queue it seems like an attempt to answer. If you flagged VLQ/NAA that will be disputed now. However since I got notified about this problem after, I have "also?" raised a custom moderator flag, indicating meta and the answer that is plagiarized without attribution.

Comment: This has been handled. Thanks for pointing it out, and sorry the bounty didn't lead to anything better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

---

[image]

Speaking as a moderator who's on the receiving end of these flags: please try to be as descriptive as possible in that text box. It helps us to figure out what's going on and we do appreciate it.